# Insert a row to Database and Table?

Tags: java, database, phpmyadmin, jtable

```
public class GetData 
{
Object[][] MyArray=null;
String [] AttributeNames;
Connection connect;
Statement statement;
String state;
int NumberOfRows,NumberOfColumns;
JTable TableData = new JTable ();
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) TableData.getModel();
public void GetData(JFrame Frame)
{
    connection();
    initComponents(Frame);
    Data();
    TableWidth();
    TableData.setVisible(true);
}
public void TableWidth ()
{
    TableColumn column = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfColumns; i++) 
    {
        column = TableData.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
        if (i == 7) {
            column.setPreferredWidth(350); 
                    }
        if (i == 0) {
            column.setPreferredWidth(25);
                    }
        if (i == 1) {
            column.setPreferredWidth(50);
                    }
        if (i == 3) {
            column.setPreferredWidth(30);
                    }
        if (i == 4) {
            column.setPreferredWidth(35);
                    }
        if (i == 5) {
            column.setPreferredWidth(50);
                    }
    }
}
public void Data () 
{
    try {
        ResultSet res = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM nhanvien");
        ResultSetMetaData RSMD = res.getMetaData();
        NumberOfColumns = RSMD.getColumnCount();
        AttributeNames = new String[NumberOfColumns];
        for(int i=0;i<NumberOfColumns;i++)
            AttributeNames[i]=RSMD.getColumnName(i+1);
        MyArray=new Object[500][NumberOfColumns];
        int R=0;
        while(res.next()) {
            for(int C=1; C<=NumberOfColumns;C++)
                MyArray[R][C-1]=res.getObject(C);
            R++;
        }         
        NumberOfRows=R;
        Object[][] TempArray=MyArray;
        MyArray=new Object[NumberOfRows][NumberOfColumns];
        for(R=0;R<NumberOfRows;R++)
            for(int C=0;C<NumberOfColumns;C++)
                MyArray[R][C]=TempArray[R][C];
        TableData.setModel(new MyTableModel());
        TableData.setVisible(true);
    }      
    catch(Exception e) {}
}
public void initComponents(JFrame f) 
{    
    model = new DefaultTableModel (new Object [][] 
        {
            {null},
            {null},
            {null},
            {null}
        },
        new String [] {""}
        ) {
          Class[] types = new Class [] {java.lang.Object.class};
          boolean[]canEdit=new boolean[]{false};

          public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) 
          {
                return types [columnIndex];
          }
          public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) 
          {
                return canEdit [columnIndex];
          }
    };
    TableData.setModel(model);
    JScrollPane ScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(TableData); 
    ScrollPane1.setBounds(30,170,950,290);
    f.add(ScrollPane1,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    TableData.setVisible(true);
}
public class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel 
{  
    public int getColumnCount() 
    {
        return (NumberOfColumns);
    }
    public int getRowCount() 
    {
        return(NumberOfRows);
    }
    public String getColumnName(int i) 
    {
        return (AttributeNames[i]);
    }
    public java.lang.Object getValueAt(int row, int column) 
    {
        return(MyArray[row][column]);
    }     
}
public void connection ()
{
    try {
        Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver");
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jdbc?      useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8";
        connect = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","");
        statement = connect.createStatement();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {}
}
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    GetData GD = new GetData ();
}
```

}

This is my code to show Database to JTable

```
public void Add (JFrame F) throws SQLException
{          
    String MNV = TX1.getText();
    String HNV = TX2.getText();
    String TNV = TX3.getText();
    String GT = TX4.getText();
    String NS = TX5.getText();
    String TD = TX6.getText();
    String SDT = TX7.getText();
    String DC = TX8.getText();       
    AD.Add("INSERT INTO `nhanvien` "
    + "(`MÃ NV`, `HỌ NV`, `TÊN NV`, `GIỚI TÍNH`, `NĂM SINH`, `TRÌNH ĐỘ`, `SỐ   ĐT`, `ĐỊA CHỈ`)"
    + " VALUES ('"+MNV+"', '"+HNV+"', '"+TNV+"', '"+GT+"', '"+NS+"', '"+TD+"', '"+SDT+"', '"+DC+"');");
    GD.GetData(F);
}
```

And this is my code to insert a row to Jtable and Database. 
My problem is sometime I add a row normally but sometime when I click to button Add the Jtable disappear but the value has still added to database and talbe, I have to close frame and open again so i can see new row. So can anyone know why this happen and does anyway to show database to Jtable (simple way). THANK YOU !

Comment: The first suggestion in your last question was to use proper variable names. Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. If you want people to read your code then follow Java conventions. The highlighting of the code is the forum is completely wrong because you don't follow the naming conventions, making your code hard to read and understand.

Comment: If was also suggested that you don't use Arrays with a hardcode size and instead use Vectors to load the data. You were given a link to a working example showing how to do this. So you have not listened to any of the suggestions. You also don't use the `addRow(...)` method to add a row to the TableModel. Part of your code uses a DefaultTableModel, another part creates a custom TableModel, by extending AbstractTableModel.